# Pandas: Group records every N days and mark duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, pandas-groupby, timedelta

I'd like to mark duplicate records within my data.

A duplicate is defined as: for each person_key, if a person_key is repeated within 25 days of the first. However, after 25 days the count is reset.

So if I had records for a person_key on Day 0, Day 20, Day 26, Day 30, the first and third would be kept, as the third is more than 25 days from the first. The second and fourth are marked as duplicate, since they are within 25 days from the "first of their group".

In other words, I think I need to identify groups of 25 day blocks, and then "dedupe" within those blocks. I'm struggling to start with to create these initial groups.

I will eventually have to apply to 5m records, so am trying to steer clear of pd.DataFrame.apply

```
person_key  date    duplicate
A   2019-01-01  False
B   2019-02-01  False
B   2019-02-12  True
C   2019-03-01  False
A   2019-01-10  True
A   2019-01-26  False
A   2019-01-28  True
A   2019-02-10  True
A   2019-04-01  False
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Let us group the dataframe by `person_key` then for each group per `person_key` again group by the custom [`grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) with frequency of `25 days` and use `cumcount` to create a sequential counter per subgroup, then compare this counter with `0` to identify the duplicate rows

```
def find_dupes():
    for _, g in df.groupby('person_key', sort=False):
        yield from g.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='25D')).cumcount().ne(0)


df['duplicate'] = list(find_dupes())
```

Result

```
print(df)

  person_key       date  duplicate
0          A 2019-01-01      False
1          B 2019-02-01      False
2          B 2019-02-12       True
3          C 2019-03-01      False
4          A 2019-01-10       True
5          A 2019-01-26      False
6          A 2019-01-28       True
7          A 2019-02-10       True
8          A 2019-04-01      False
```

Comment: On application I've realised there is an edge case which has highlighted the solution doesn't actually work as intended.

If the C person key had date 2019-01-01, then record for person A 2019-01-10 would be marked as NOT a duplicate.
Since the grouper counts from the first date across all person_keys, rather than for each person_key.
Is that your understanding too?
Do you have any ideas for having this 25d count be for each person_key?

It seems that the grouper is not taking account of person_key at all.

Comment: In addition, even within a person_key group your solution would count 25 days from the first date in that group.

Whereas I actually want to count 25 days from the first date in that group, then if there's another (valid) record after 25 days, to reset the count *from that record*

Comment: thanks for following up. I think there is still something not quite working here. If you add some records to person A: 03-28, 03-29, 03-30, you will see that the grouper is counting 25d from the first record of person A. But I am looking to "reset" the count to 0 after 25d have passed from the first record of person A, then restart the count with the first date 25 days after the first record, and repeat until all duplicates are found. Does that make sense? Happy to edit the original question to add an example with this edge case.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution will group based on 25 day increments for the whole df, but the second solution will use the date in each person_key:

```
df.groupby(['person_key',pd.Grouper(key = 'date',freq = '25D')])['person_key'].transform(lambda x: x.duplicated())
```

or

```
df.groupby('person_key').resample('25D',on='date')['person_key'].transform(lambda x: x.duplicated()).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
7     True
8    False
```